# Read Words from a PDF or DOC file in React or Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, file, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple React application (with no back-end servers), hosted on Firebase.

The application takes in a file(either a word document or a pdf) and stores it in firebase storage and stores the metadata in firestore.

I have a requirement to read the number of words in the file and if it is more than 500, block the upload.

I have been searching for a way to do this using just React and i think it cant be done. The other option i have is to use Cloud Functions in Firebase which use NodeJs and even with that i am not finding any solution to do this.

At this point in time, i cant setup a proper back-end server to do this work.

I would be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into using FS for node.js in a cloud function. I've used FS to read data from a document before in a node environment, but only from a document that lives on the computer. Maybe cloud functions will let you "download" a file from your database and use FS(file-system) for node to read it. https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp

Comment: That is a good suggestion, thanks. But i dont want it to be uploaded to storage before i could count the words. Ideally, i would like to count the words before it could be stored so that i can put a notification saying that the document exceeds the word limit and ask the user to make it shorter.

Comment: This is office document reader for node that only reads the metadata (so not the whole file is needed). Maybe you could implement something on your front-end code? https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-document-properties

Comment: This npm package looks like it could be the solution. Let me try implementing it and see if it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could use a Callable Function to upload the file to the function's local storage, process the document using the Vision API and **if** it acceptable, only then save it to GCS. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf

Answer (score 0):

A few pdf readers exist for node which can be installed in Cloud Functions since most don't support in browser. It is advised to upload the pdf to storage to save processing issues, simply add the reference path to the Cloud Function payload and delete it after completion.

`pdfreader` at this current time the best available for PDF's parsing, but requires a node environment such as Cloud Functions.
The second issue is reading image-based pdf's which require OCR, link provided.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-ocr